# subtracting strings in shell script (easy fix)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, command

I know this is a really dumb question, but how do I make:

```
nlength=$(expr length $(route -n|grep ^0.0.0.0|cut -d' ' -f 10))"-1
```

Equal 10
Currently If I run this command, it sets nlength to "11-1"
Do I have to convert a string into a value first, before it will work?
Sorry for asking such a stupid question.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just do arithmetic on BASH command like that without any utility like `expr`, `bc` or internal `((...))`.

Your command can be reduced to:

```
nlength=$(route -n | awk '/^0\.0\.0\.0/{print ($10-1)}')
```